# Issues with javascript Date() in Safari and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I fetch the following date from the DB

```
"2013-11-07 10:41:00"
```

Which seemingly can only be parsed in Chrome, NOT Safari or Firefox.

//Firstly, the timestamp is pulled from the DB and put into the array here

```
$getActivityUpdates1 = mysql_query("SELECT s.id, u.name, u.profilePic, s.userid, s.content, s.time1, s.imageKey FROM status_updates s 
        INNER JOIN users1 u ON u.id = s.userid 
        WHERE competitionId = '$competitionId' AND s.id > '$lastPollId' ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 0, 20");

    $results = array('items' => array());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getActivityUpdates1)) 
    {
        $results['items'][] = array(
        'statusid' => $row['id'],
        'name' => $row['name'], 
        'profilePic' => $row['profilePic'],
        'content' => $row['content'],
        'time1' => $row['time1'],
        'imageKey' => $row['imageKey'],
        );

        if ($lastPollId < $row["id"]) {
            $lastPollId = $row["id"];
        }
    }

    $results["lastPollId"] = $lastPollId;

    die(json_encode($results));
```

//sparta.js - Here I have a basic function to convert the timestamp into a "pretty date"

```
function getNiceDate(d) {
  var date = new Date(d).add(-new Date().getTimezoneOffset()).minutes(); //Problem with the format here?
  var now = new Date();                                                  //Problem with the format here?  
  var minutesDifference =  parseInt((now - date) / (60 * 1000));

  if  (minutesDifference < 2) {
    return "Just now";
  } else if (minutesDifference < 60) {
    return minutesDifference + " minutes ago";
  } else if (minutesDifference < 60 * 24) {
    var hoursDifference = parseInt(minutesDifference / 60);
    return hoursDifference + " hours ago";
  }

  return date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");                             //Problem with the format here?    
}
```

//Then we call the getNiceDate() function like so, as we build the HTML. 
//entryData.time1 is the Timestamp from DB in following format "2013-11-07 10:41:00"

```
var activityTimeElement = entry.find(".actTime");
activityTimeElement.text(getNiceDate(entryData.time1));                //function getNiceDate() used here.
activityTimeElement.attr("data-timestamp", entryData.time1);
```

//Output and Expected Results

```
In chrome : "35 minutes ago" or "Just now" or if more than a few hours ago, the timestamp. 

In Safari : "NaN-NaN-NaN NaN:NaN"

In Firefox : "NaN-NaN-NaN NaN:NaN"
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: how do you call getNiceDate?

Comment: how does `d` look like?

Comment: How is entryData.time1 formatted!?

Comment: give us an example of `entryData.time1` :) If it's in format "yyyy-mm-dd" then is here the mistake

Comment: In the JSON response, the time1 is formatted like so : "time1":"2013-11-07 09:39:32"

Comment: So you were right @chumkiu - so how should I go about getting it to work in all browsers :D

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Sorry to be a pain @chumkiu , could you help slightly with the syntax. Should I change the format in the PHP (which generates the JSON response) or in the Javascript?

Comment: I think the simplest solution is to pass by php the timestamp directly (don't forget to multiply *1000)

Comment: Hmm, I pull the TIMESTAMP from my MYSQL DB, that could be a bit tricky right?

Comment: Hi guys, added the entire code now, still not got this to work. Wondering if I should convert the timestamp in the PHP or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check

[ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

or

[IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14)

According to these your date-time string must be formatted according to this:

1995-02-05T00:00:00

This Link might help you too:

[JavaScript new Date() Returning NaN in IE or Invalid Date in Safari](http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari)

Comment: Ah, so perhaps it's just the 'T' that needs to go into the date time string?

Comment: Might be that these browsers need the T...heres a link to mozilla where the Date Constructor Parameter is described: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: So, weird question but how would I add the 't' to the format, given I insert the timestamp with MYSQL NOW() into the DB?

Comment: Im not that good in MYSQL, but I guess you can't set it on insert. Better write a function, that parses your date after retreiving and formats it properly. Check last added link in my answer too, it says, there are problems with date-format too in safari...

Comment: Accept my answer as right if it helped you solve the problem pls ;) Happy coding ;)